# How do I limit request size in Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, http, rack

In Rack-based app, what is the best way to refuse requests that are excessively long (considering URL incl. query, headers and body)?

(I mean Rack, the Ruby server middleware :D)

Answer (score -1):

You can give a look to the attributes of the incoming request ! You will have some ideas.
the request object is a hash so you can inspect it and see how you wanna handle it.